# Cordova : Blank white screen after camera capture

Tags: cordova, camera, screen, cordova-plugins

I am developing a phonegap app with camera functionality.

I use following to invoke camera

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
                             onSuccess,
                             onFail,
                             { 
                               quality: 40,
                               destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
                               sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA 
                             }
                           );
```

I am getting a blank white screen after capturing image and press ok button in motog 2 (android 6.0.0) and  HTC (android 5.0.1) .

I also tried changing to two other plugins for camera but the same issue persists.

Can someone help me to solve this?

```
 function onSuccess(imageURI) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function (fileSystem) {
                fileSystem.file(function (file) { 
                    fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);    
                    saveValueToDb(fileName, imageURI, file.type, file.size);//in saveValueToDb() I save this datas to websql                    
                });
        });
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

Comment: Which are your onSuccess and onFail functions? Can you post them?

Comment: @mobiledevnewbie Any error trace in console?

Comment: @sailens : please find below the onSuccess and onFail functions 

   function onSuccess(imageURI) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function (fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.file(function (file) {
     fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
     saveValueToDb(fileName, imageURI, file.type, file.size);//in saveValueToDb() I save this datas to websql
    
    });
  });
    }
 
 function onFail(message) {
  console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
 }

Comment: What does the console is telling you?

Comment: @Gandhi: I am using Google chrome's USB debugging and no errors/warnings is shown in the console

Comment: @sailens : I am using Google chrome's USB debugging and no errors/warnings is shown in the console

Comment: @mobiledevnewbie Is it getting into success callback and invoking saveValueToDb method? Did you debugged further?

Comment: @Gandhi : Yes the success callback works and the details are saving to db.But the screen there after is a blank white screen.

Comment: @mobiledevnewbie So what are you expecting afterwards? If you wanna take the user to someother page, then you gotta redirect him to the next page programatically inside success call back

Comment: @Gandhi : I tried redirecting the page using jquery mobile changePage but still the whitescreen persist. If I run with debugger connected and when the white screen is present and clicking in console area( like clicking network or resources or console etc )  closes the white screen and displays the page.

Comment: @mobiledevnewbie did you tried other ways of redirection like window.location or replace?